# How to properly phrase a sentence in which the two key words of the OR clause use different prepositions

Tags: prepositions, phrasing

Given these two sentences:

- The mixin is a method of adding to the properties of a Javascript class.
- The mixin is a method of removing from the properties of a Javascript class.

I'd like to combine them into a single sentence, but the verbs have different prepositions. So the use of two prepositions in the combined sentence feels clumsy:

- The mixin is a method of adding to or removing from the properties of a Javascript class.

Is there a less clumsy way to phrase this? Possibly using a single preposition? I'm actually interested in the general case or a rule, not just this specific case with which I am dealing right now.

Comment: This use of the word "method" is likely to be confusing, since that term has a specific meaning in OOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the directional prepostions "to" and "from", you can use "of" in both the original and the combined sentences.

> The mixin is a method of adding or removing properties of a Javascript class.

Or use the possessive form.

> The mixin is a method of adding or removing a JavaScript class's properties.

Comment: Good. Also, "removing *from* the properties" was a bit off.

Comment: *The mixin is a method of adding properties of a Javascript class.* ← That doesn't make sense.

Comment: "mixin" is the name for a type of class that performs this operation.

Comment: Yes, your second idea is often applicable to the general case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest

> The `mixin` is a method which [modifies](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/modify) the properties of a Javascript class.

The suggestion is a verb, not a preposition, but is a less clumsy way to phrase it.

Comment: Thank you, but as stated I'm actually interested in the general case or a rule, not just this specific case.